# ¿Cómo actualizar base de datos con ajax? No hace nada

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Estoy empezando con Javascript, Ajax y JQUERY. He encontrado un código parecido a lo que quiero realizar y estoy intentando modificarlo para conseguirlo. Mi idea es que cada 3 segundos, se realice un consulta a la base de datos por si hubiese algún producto distinto, pero no tengo conocimientos suficientes para hacer esto y no me arroja ningún error, pero **no hace nada**. Alguna ayuda, ¿por favor?

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
        <style>
            #counter {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 40px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            function update(){
                var current = $('#contenedor').text();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "consulta.php",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#contenedor').text();
                    }
                });
            }

            setInterval(update, 3000);
        });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>


        <section class="content">
            <p>CONSULTA BASE DE DATOS</p>
            <p><span id="contenedor">0</span>.
        </section>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Este es mi código de **consulta.php**

```
global $wpdb;

$consulta = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM productos WHERE producto_status='terminado' GROUP BY producto_usuario" ); 

  var_dump ($consulta);
```

Comment: No puedes crear tus propios archivos PHP y esperar a que WordPress los reconozca, WordPress ya tiene un archivo que maneja peticiones AJAX (admin-ajax.php). Te recomiendo este artículo de blog: https://desarrollowp.com/blog/tutoriales/ajax-en-wordpress-la-manera-tradicional/

Answer (score 0):

**Buen día**

La parte en PHP desconozco que obtienes en `$consulta` (con `$wpdb->get_results`); por consiguiente asumí que es un datos que del lado Ajax (del cliente) se recibe lo que realmente deseas (un texto).

Ahora la parte de Ajax en vez del `success` usa el `complete` (es el que uso regularmente); como a continuación te sugiero:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "consulta.php",
   complete: function(data) {
                 $('#contenedor').text(data.responseText);
   }
});
```

En lo anterior estoy asumiendo que la respuesta del PHP es un texto, si es un JSON o un string que representa un JSON deberás realizar los pasos necesarios (según corresponda) para tratar y presentar los datos como corresponda.

> **Editado**

Bueno en [Wordpress $wpdb->get_results() query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800411/wordpress-wpdb-get-results-query) es al parecer un conjunto de objetos que tendrá por cada uno los atributos con el nombre de los campos retornados del SQL; por tanto te sugiero que le pongas un alias al `COUNT(*)` algo como `COUNT(*) TOTAL`; en caso así tendrias en `$consulta` un array de objetos que tendria como único valor TOTAL; siendo accesible mediante su indice o iterativamente (mira el link anterior); `$consulta[0...N-1]->TOTAL`.

Te sugiero en vez del var_dump; de momento te asegures devolver un string en tu PHP:

```
/* Lo que haces en primeras líneas en tu PHP donde asignas $consulta asumo lo dejas; lo siguiente es para sustituir el "var_dump($consulta);" */
$cadenaFormada="";

foreach( $result as $consulta) {
   $cadenaFormada.="<br />".$result->TOTAL;
}

echo $cadenaFormada;
```

En caso que lo anterior falle; te sugiero probar ejecutando directamente el script; pones en tu navegador la url que corresponda (asumo `localhost`) http://localhost y le colocas la demas ruta; por ejemplo: si esta en raiz del sitio sería `http://localhost/consulta.php` si esta dentro de una carpeta digamos `script` `http://localhost/script/consulta.php` así por el estilo; el resultado de esto debe ser que en el navegador se muestre cada número (TOTAL) que se obtiene (que sería solo uno por no hay group by o algo para agrupar y se obtengan varios).

Comment: Hola Roberto, muchas gracias por tu rápida y atenta respuesta. En realidad no obtengo nada en "$consulta". Por eso no sé cuál es ni dónde está el problema del código. En realidad, mi intención es que lo que obtenga con $consulta es que sea un número, como consecuencia de haber hecho un "SELECT COUNT", pero quizá en el futuro (al variar el programa), mi consulta devuelva texto y números. He probado tu código, pero no veo ninguna variación, sigo sin obtener resultado...

Comment: Muchas gracias a @Roberto León Oramas y a Lucas Accastello, pero de momento no consigo hacerlo funcionar. No devuelve error, pero tampoco devuelve el resultado de la consulta. Todo lo que he he puesto en javascript y ajax lo estoy ejecutando en el sidebar.php de wordpress, dentro de mi theme, no sé si ese será el motivo. Y el archivo consulta.php está dentro del theme también. Lo único que me muestra todo como resultado es el 0 de <span id="contenedor">0</span>.

Answer (score 0):

Ante todo estimo que realizas la conexión a la base de datos antes de realizar la consulta, por contrario tu consulta nunca funcionaría. 
Lo que te recomiendo hacer es devolver el resultado de tu consulta en forma JSON. Debería quedar algo así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
     <style>
       #counter {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 40px;
       }
     </style>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {  
         function update(){
         var current = $('#contenedor').text();

         $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "consulta.php",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response) {
          $('#contenedor').text(response);
         }
         });
        }

       setInterval(update, 3000);
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


 <section class="content">
  <p>CONSULTA BASE DE DATOS</p>
  <p><span id="contenedor">0</span>.
 </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Fijate que agrego el atributo dataType: 'json' en el $.ajax. Es importante especificarle que la respuesta será un json.

Y tu PHP debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
 global $wpdb;

 $consulta = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM productos WHERE 
  producto_status='terminado' GROUP BY producto_usuario" ); 

 json_encode($consulta);
```

[json_encode](http://nz.php.net/json_encode) te permite convertir tus resultados de la consulta en formato json.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Lucas Accastello, pero de momento no consigo hacerlo funcionar. No devuelve error, pero tampoco devuelve el resultado de la consulta. Todo lo que he he puesto en javascript y ajax lo estoy ejecutando en el sidebar.php de wordpress, dentro de mi theme, no sé si ese será el motivo. Y el archivo consulta.php está dentro del theme también. Lo único que me muestra todo como resultado es el 0 de <span id="contenedor">0</span>.